# How to receive object from C++ standard library via DLL-file in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have a DLL-file (written in C++), which ReadTemp function returns two integers (documentation states, that the function returns a list consisting of two integers).

I do not know how to receive the object in VB.net from the DLL-file.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    TextBox1.Text = ReadTemp(2)
End Sub
```

The DLL is called from this code:

```
Private Declare Function ReportSN Lib "VCDLL.dll" () As Int32
Private Declare Function ReadTemp Lib "VCDLL.dll" (ByVal SN As Int32) As Single
```

EDIT:

C++ code from the DLL-file added:

```
list<float> ReadTemp(int SN) {

    list <float> temp(2);

    if () // Test if connection to COM-port is good
    {
        for () // Runs only 2 times
        {   
        temp.push_back(fVal);
        }
    }
    else
    {   
        // Ugly error message
        temp.push_back(-999);
        temp.push_back(-999);
        return temp;
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Please show the function's signature in C++.

Comment: @GSerg I have added the C++ function

Comment: possible duplicate of [Howto call an unmanaged C++ function with a std::vector as parameter from C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772120/howto-call-an-unmanaged-c-function-with-a-stdvector-as-parameter-from-c)

Comment: This is not "multiple output," this is an object from the C++ standard library. See the link for a workaround.

Comment: @GSerg I am not sure I fully understand how the link can help me? What do I need to change in the C++ code to receive multiple output? - it is properly the best to avoid returning an object in C++ to VB.net...

Comment: You need to create a simple wrapper in C++ that will call the `ReadTemp` and return the values from the list in some other way, e.g. as an output parameter of type `*float` that you will declare as array of `Single` on the VB.NET side.