# How can I pass struct from C# managed to C++ unmanaged DLL and get struct in result?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, struct, interop

I do not understand c++ much so I am adding all of the code from which dll was made.

**C++ **
**Calculator.h**

```
#ifndef CALCULATOR_H
#define CALCULATOR_H

#include "global.h"

struct CALCULATORSHARED_EXPORT Input {
    double a;
    double b;
};

struct CALCULATORSHARED_EXPORT Result {
    double sum;
    double diff;
    double prod;
    double div;
};
```

**global.h**

```
#ifndef CALCULATOR_GLOBAL_H
#define CALCULATOR_GLOBAL_H

#if defined(CALCULATOR_EXPORTS)
#  define CALCULATORSHARED_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#  define CALCULATORSHARED_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#endif // CALCULATOR_GLOBAL_H
```

**calculator.h**

```
#include "calculator.h"

Result calculate( const Input& input) {
    Result result;

    result.sum = input.a + input.b;
    result.diff = input.a - input.b;
    result.prod = input.a * input.b;
    result.div = input.a / input.b;

    return result;
}
```

**C#**

```
[DllImport("Calculator.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern Result calculate(Input input);


        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]

        public struct Input
        {
            public double a;
            public double b;
        };

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]

        public struct Result
        {            
            public double sum;
            public double diff;
            public double prod;
            public double div;
        };

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Input input;
            Result result;
            input.a = 5;
            input.b = 6;
            result = calculate(input);    
        }
```

I am getting `Unable to find an entry point named 'calculate' in DLL 'Calculator.dll'.`

Comment: Are you in fact exporting `calculate` from `Calculator.dll`?

Comment: @GSerg I do not quite understand what you mean by exporting calculate from Calculator.dll. I have updated my question with all c++ code from which this dll was made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do:

```
extern "C"
{
    CALCULATORSHARED_EXPORT Result calculate(const Input& input)
    {
    }
}
```

You don't need to mark `CALCULATORSHARED_EXPORT` the two structures (`Input` and `Result`).

The `extern "C"` otherwise the name of the function will be mangled, the `CALCULATORSHARED_EXPORT` otherwise the function won't be exported.

And the C# signature must be:

```
public static extern Result calculate(ref Input input);
```

because in C++ it is a `Input&`.

Clearly then

```
result = calculate(ref input);
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: can you please tell me what would be the c# equivalent of `std::vector< double > c;` ? I am adding it to the input along with double a and b within the input struct. I can post it as a new question if you want me to.

Comment: @Arbaaz no hope of marshaling a `vector<>`. Pass an array + length of the array

Comment: If we were to assume that this the dll which I have to use without making changes (ie . with vector) 
Does it mean I can not work with it?

Comment: @Arbaaz You can use C++/cli (the C++ with .NET) to build a "bridge", but I consider it to be a pain. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/a/3772263/613130

Comment: @Arbaaz Note that the called method, if it accepts a `vector<>`, then it can't be in an `extern "C" { }`, and just discovering its mangled name (that will be something like `?calculateABCDE`) is a (little) pain

Comment: This is the super simplified version of the actual dll that I have to work with. And it has `vector<double>` I can ask the guy (third party) who created C++ dll to make minor changes to it but nothing big. Looks like I am gonna have to look into `C++/cli ` that you were referring to.

Comment: I have to admit that for a guy like me who is not very experienced and has no C++ background, the C++/cli seems a little overwhelming. Do you have any pointers where I should start reading about creating wrappers in C++/cli?

Comment: @Arbaaz Look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/3772263/613130 . Yours will be much simpler (the code in the response had to *return* the vector, you'll have to *pass* it)